# fatal error LNK 1104:cannot open file:'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib'

Tags: c++, windows, boost

there is a fatal error that is LNK 1104:cannot open file:'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib' when i try to generate resolution for a arcsim project(version:0.2.1-windows)--adptiveCloth via MS vs2013.And i have added boost_1.55 to my project,and a fatal error occured as previously mentioned,i do not know what led to this?What should i do ?Need Help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you bulit boost? How are you telling whatever build system where the boost libraries are? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: yeah,i have build boost.i unzip Boost library in C:\Boost and ran bootstrap.bat and b2.exe install via Visual Studio 2013'Develpoer Command Prompt.Then it created two folders for me--C:\Boost\include and C:\Boost\lib,Which I added to VC++ Directories > Include Directories;Linker > General > Additional Library Directories

Comment: And does that lib file name exist in `C:\Boost\lib`? If not you need to make sure your boost build settings match your project build settings

Comment: yeah,i check it and the file does not exist in C:\Boost\lib.But i do not kown where to set boost build settings and how to make sure the settings match my project build settings.Is it in MS VS?

Comment: if that exact lib file name exists in `C:\Boost\lib` then `C:\Boost\lib` isn't in your additional library directories